# Adjusting Timeline Label

Tags: cubism.js

I've recently loaded a days worth of time series data into multiple horizon graphs.  The data is from a static json file.

How do I adjust time header start date/time and get it to correspond with the step used in the graph?

For example my data is from Oct 10, 2012.  Each data point was collected every 30 seconds.  I'm not sure how to manipulate serverDelay to get what I want.

var context = cubism.context()
    .serverDelay(new Date(2012, 10, 10) - Date.now())
    .step(30*60*1000)
    .size(2880)
    .stop();